# Paperclip gem not working in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

My rails app works great in development. In production I get the following error when launching the app at Heroku:[image]

It references a helper method I defined:

```
def image_for(movie)
  if movie.image.exists?
    image_tag(movie.image.url)
  else
    image_tag('placeholder.png')
  end
end
```

This started after installing the paperclip gem but it doesn't happen in development. Does anyone know how to fix this error. My next step is to install an older version of the gem but I wanted some advice first. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put gem 'aws-sdk' in your Gemfile ?
It seems Rails can not find Paperclip::Storage::S3::AWS which is provided by aws-sdk gem.

Comment: And you put it under the production group ? Can you open a console in production and type Paperclip::Storage::S3::AWS and check if the error happen again ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by downgrading the aws-sdk gem:
gem 'aws-sdk','<2.0'